# NameError: name 'txtDisplay' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a scientific calculator using the tkinter module in python 3. When I run the code it runs fine until I press any key on the calculator, then it gives the following error:

```
C:\Users\Tauseef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/Tauseef/Desktop/scratch.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tauseef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Tauseef/Desktop/scratch.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    btn[i]["command"] = lambda x = numberpad[i]: added_value.numberEnter(x)
  File "C:/Users/Tauseef/Desktop/scratch.py", line 26, in numberEnter
    firstnum = txtDisplay.get()
NameError: name 'txtDisplay' is not defined
```

Comment: The error is clear, no? `NameError: name 'txtDisplay' is not defined`

Comment: Looks like `txtDisplay` is not defined when you call `get` on it. Can't tell you much more than that with what you gave us to work with.

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of scratch.py where you used `txtDisplay`. See how to create a [mcve].